# While loop in C don't break even after encountering a NULL character

Tags: c, while-loop

here is the code to add the numbers present in an Alphanumeric string :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int total=0;
char ch;
printf("enter the string\n");
ch=getchar();
while(ch!='\0')
{
    printf("I am here !!");
    if (!(isalpha(ch)))
        total+=(int)ch;
    ch=(char)getchar();
    printf("I am here !!");
}
printf("\ntotal is %d",total);
return 0;
}
```

No matter what characters I input , it gives 4 " I am here " for each character.

I tried to use

```
while((ch=getchar())!='\0');
```

but it gives the same problem .

Comment: I really want to know how you input the `nul` character? how is it?

Comment: Use `while(ch!='\n')` and make `ch` an `int`, not a `char`. Also, remove all the casts.

Comment: Your loop never encounters a NULL character, so it never breaks.

Comment: @iharob I wanted to run it till I encounter '\n' . I am a newbie at C sorry !!

Comment: @yashC It's ok, but can I give you advice? Ok I will, don't ask someone about something you can figure out by yourself, it's an important part of teaching yourself and learning how to teach yourself, if you discover this by your own, you will **never** forget it, so ask only when you really run out of ideas. :) Also, just for courtesy accept one of the ansewers below, please don't pick mine for courtesy, pick one that really helped understand. You can't delete your question because there are answers with positive score and it would be rude.

Comment: @iharob Thanks alot for your help and guidance (: . I was accepting the answer below but at first it showed " Cant Accept with in 3 mins " and then " error occurred , try again " .

Comment: 1) getchar() returns an 'int', not a 'char'.  2) the return key press is what is causing the double execution problem.  at the bottom of the loop insert 'while( getchar() != '\n');'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`getchar` does not return `'\0'` at the end of the input: it is *not* reading from a null-terminated C string, but from a console, file, or some other stream.

When no additional input is available, `getchar` returns `EOF`. That is the condition you should be checking to decide when to stop your loop.

Stack Overflow offers many good examples of how to implement a loop reading `getchar` ([link#1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2462728/335858); [link#2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22445120/335858); please note the data types used in the examples).

Comment: BTW The `EOF` character can be input with `CTRL-Z`, when using a console.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it doesn't work is because `'\0'` cannot be inserted from the keyboard, so `getchar()` is unlikely to be able to return `'\0'`, a correct way of testing for the end of input would be

```
int ch;

while (((ch = getchar()) != EOF) && (ch != '\n'))
```

This is because `EOF` means, that the user intentionally wanted to stop entering data, and `'\n'` is usually the last thing that will be seen when `stdin` is flushed, since it triggers the flushing.

Comment: `echo -e "\0" | ./a.out`

Comment: @SanderDeDycker interesting, but I don't think the OP was doing that.